# How to synchronously get data using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm trying to get data from Axios but while the data is being fetch the return statement gets executed, I think.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function Overall() {

const [post, setPost] = useState({
    date:null,
    total:null
});

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(){
        
        await axios.get(`https://data.covid19india.org/v4/min/data.min.json`).then((response) => {
            console.log("Inside Then block");
            setPost({'total':Object.entries(response.data).map(([k,v])=>
                // console.log(k,v.meta.last_updated,v.total.confirmed)
                v.total.confirmed
                ).reduce((prev, curr)=>prev+curr,0)
                })
            setPost({'date':Object.entries(response.data)[0][1].meta.last_updated})
        });
    }
    fetchData()
    console.log("Data Fetched");
    
}, []);

console.log("Post: ",post);
return (
    <div className='overall-container'>
        <div>
            <h2>India</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Total: {post.total}</h2>
            <h2>Date: {post.date}</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

The problem is that in return only `{post.date}` is working while `{post.curr}` is not. I don't know why? I'm new to react so I don't know much. I would appreciate if someone could explain this.

Comment: (1) you're overwriting the data in the `post` state instead of merging them, and (2) if you're using await there is no need to use `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you meant `{post.total}` instead of `{post.curr}`

You could change from:

```
            setPost({'total':Object.entries(response.data).map(([k,v])=>
                // console.log(k,v.meta.last_updated,v.total.confirmed)
                v.total.confirmed
                ).reduce((prev, curr)=>prev+curr,0)
                })
            setPost({'date':Object.entries(response.data)[0][1].meta.last_updated})
```

To:

```
setPost({
    total: Object.entries(response.data).map(([k,v])=>
           // console.log(k,v.meta.last_updated,v.total.confirmed)
           v.total.confirmed
           ).reduce((prev, curr)=>prev+curr,0),
    date: Object.entries(response.data)[0][1].meta.last_updated
});
```

And it should work. However, maybe it'd be better to seperate date and total into two different states?

Comment: It works. Would you please enlighten me as to why it work now?

Comment: Well setPost is like a setter to your post state, so when u had two setters (lets call total setter A, and date setter B). setter A set the post state where total is defined and date is undefined. And then after setter B set post state where total is undefined and date is defined. So after B has executed total was not defined.

Comment: Yea and also when u are using await theres no need to use .then. You could just do `const response = await axios.get(...)` probably.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad practice to do async stuff in useEffect. You should create a separate function and call it from useEffect.

Your error is caused because you call setPost to update total and then once again to update date.

When you call setPost it will erase previous value for post. If you need to keep previous value you can do:

```
setPost((prev) => ({
  ...prev,
  date: new Date()
}));
```

In your code you should call setPost only once

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Overall() {

const [post, setPost] = useState({});

const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://data.covid19india.org/v4/min/data.min.json`)
        // tranform your response and then set it to state at once
        const total =  1 // replace with your total
        const date = new Date() // replace with your date
        setPost({ total, date })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()  
}, []);

console.log("Post: ",post);
return (
    <div className='overall-container'>
        <div>
            <h2>India</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Total: {post?.total}</h2>
            <h2>Date: {post?.date}</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `This is a bad practice to do async stuff in useEffect.` Could you explain why as well?

Comment: ah nvm you just added it as a seperate async function.